# Scala toString function

Tags: scala, tostring

I have a class which has a method that prints out a string. I would like to override the toString-function so that the string is printed like t|h|i|s. How do I do that?

Comment: You should really provide more details and probably some code of what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to interpret your question as "has a method that **returns** a string" rather than "has a method that **prints out** a string," because I'm just *guessing* that's what you meant, and the question you asked would be a much harder problem.

Here is a class `Foo` which has a method `bar` that returns a string. The class `Foo` overrides the `toString` method such that it returns the value of `bar` with the `|` character interspersed.

```
scala> class Foo(val bar: String) {
     |   override def toString: String = bar.mkString("|")
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> val x = new Foo("this")
x: Foo = t|h|i|s

scala> x.bar
res0: String = this
```